# Can someone explain me short _linear function from TensorFlow RNN code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Here the core(mb) function of tensorflow RNN implimentation

[Linear map:](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L846-L891)

```
def _linear(args, output_size, bias, bias_start=0.0, scope=None):
  """Linear map: sum_i(args[i] * W[i]), where W[i] is a variable.
  Args:
    args: a 2D Tensor or a list of 2D, batch x n, Tensors.
    output_size: int, second dimension of W[i].
    bias: boolean, whether to add a bias term or not.
    bias_start: starting value to initialize the bias; 0 by default.
    scope: VariableScope for the created subgraph; defaults to "Linear".
  Returns:
    A 2D Tensor with shape [batch x output_size] equal to
    sum_i(args[i] * W[i]), where W[i]s are newly created matrices.
  Raises:
    ValueError: if some of the arguments has unspecified or wrong shape.
  """
  if args is None or (nest.is_sequence(args) and not args):
    raise ValueError("`args` must be specified")
  if not nest.is_sequence(args):
    args = [args]

  # Calculate the total size of arguments on dimension 1.
  total_arg_size = 0
  shapes = [a.get_shape().as_list() for a in args]
  for shape in shapes:
    if len(shape) != 2:
      raise ValueError("Linear is expecting 2D arguments: %s" % str(shapes))
    if not shape[1]:
      raise ValueError("Linear expects shape[1] of arguments: %s" % str(shapes))
    else:
      total_arg_size += shape[1]

  # Now the computation.
  with vs.variable_scope(scope or "Linear"):
    matrix = vs.get_variable("Matrix", [total_arg_size, output_size])
    if len(args) == 1:
      res = math_ops.matmul(args[0], matrix)
    else:
      res = math_ops.matmul(array_ops.concat(1, args), matrix)
    if not bias:
      return res
    bias_term = vs.get_variable(
        "Bias", [output_size],
        initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(bias_start))
  return res + bias_term
```

So as far as I can undestand `args` contains values and we should multiplicate(dot product) it with weights Matrix `W[i]` and add `bias`. The thing that I can't undestand:

When we are calling `vs.get_variable("Matrix", [total_arg_size, output_size])` without reusing variable flag, will we create each time new weights Matrix that is randomly initialized every time? I think in such case we will fail.. I can't find `scope.reuse_variables()` or `reuse=True` anywhere in `rnn_cell.py` code. And can't find where "Matrix" `variable(weights)` are updated or saved... so looks like every time this will be random weights. How does all this works? Are we using random weights matrix each time? Maybe someone can explaine how `_linear` works?

Comment: If any of the post answers you question. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`linear` computes `sum_i(args[i] * W[i]) + bias` where `W` is a list of matrix variables of size `n x outputsize` and `bias` is a variable of size `outputsize`.

Tensorflow uses the transpose notation---row vector on the left times the transpose of the matrix---so in `linear`, the args are a list of row vectors.

**Where is the matrix `W` and offset `b`?  This is fetched from memory based on the variable current scope, because `W` and `b` are variable tensors that are learned values.**

[Check this](https://esciencegroup.com/2016/03/04/fun-with-recurrent-neural-nets-one-more-dive-into-cntk-and-tensorflow/)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `tf.variable_scope` says that if the `variable_scope` "reuse" argument is not specified then the default argument is `None`. This is the case in the code you provided: `with vs.variable_scope(scope or "Linear")`.

When the scope reuse is not specified or `None`, the parent's scope reuse setting is inherited. [See here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variable_scope).

For your particular example, the RNN cell's weight variables are shared without specifying `reuse=True` in the `_linear` function's variable scope because the `rnn` function, defined in `rnn.py`, which calls the rnn cell has its variable scope set to `reuse`.

See the following excerpt [from `rnn.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py):

```
def rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state=None, dtype=None,
        sequence_length=None, scope=None):

    ....

    for time, input_ in enumerate(inputs):
        if time > 0: varscope.reuse_variables()
        # pylint: disable=cell-var-from-loop
        call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
        # pylint: enable=cell-var-from-loop
        if sequence_length is not None:
            (output, state) = _rnn_step(
                time=time,
                sequence_length=sequence_length,
                min_sequence_length=min_sequence_length,
                max_sequence_length=max_sequence_length,
                zero_output=zero_output,
                state=state,
                call_cell=call_cell,
                state_size=cell.state_size)
        else:
            (output, state) = call_cell()
```